# What is wrong in this code for checking if a number is a prime?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to send array to method and checking the array integer values whether they are prime or not and then storing all prime numbers in new array and sending it back.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FunPrime {

    public static int[] calculate(int[] arr) {
        int arr2[] = {};
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) {
                if (arr[i] % j == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 2)
                    break;
            }
            if (count <= 2) {

                arr2[m] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return arr2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int no[] = { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 22, 43 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(calculate(no)));
    }
}
```

Comment: you tell us whats wrong with your code

Comment: You are making arr2 size 0 so you won't be able to add any numbers to it.

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++)` - What this loop for?

Comment: use `arraylist` instead of `array`

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use `new` to allocate that memory before you start using references. I also think you can do away with the x = x and x = 1; then you can stop your loop with a break. That should be quicker. Something like

```
for (int y = 2; y < x; y++) if (x % y == 0) { result = true; break; }
```

[How to find number of prime numbers between two integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288747/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-between-two-integers)

Comment: but your answer is not an answer

Comment: @ImmerAllein the question was not a question

Comment: yes, it is. as you can see _"what.."_ and _"?"_ shows that it is a question

Comment: @ImmerAllein oh haha the title.

Comment: @ImmerAllein, better?

Answer (score 2):

In Java if we write

```
int array = new int [10] ;
```

Then its a dynamic initialization and not static. Therefore you need to allocate memory statically by

```
int array = { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 22, 43 };
```

also in future if you want to initialize an array to zero then you can use

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
arr[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are, at least, three things wrong...

**First...**

```
int arr2[] = {};
```

Is creating an empty array with no positions available to store any content, this means the moment you try and access any element within it, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

You should initialise the array to the desired length, for example...

```
int arr2[] = new int[arr.length];
```

**Two...**

The value of `count` is never re-initialised after it is used, this means that it keeps getting incremented on each loop, meaning it will only ever be capable of reporting the first successful match, instead, you should initialise the `count` back to `0` on each loop, for example...

```
for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) {
```

**Third...**

`m` is never incremented, meaning that you are always storing the sucessful match to the first element position in the `arr2`, don't forget to increment the value, for example...

```
arr2[m] = arr[i];
m++;
```

**Bonus**

The problem with this is, this will return `0` for the elements that don't match, for example...

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This might not be desired

You can "trim" the result using `System.arraycopy`, but you will need to make one minor change first.  The `m` value indicates the number of matches, this is useful, but because it's declared in the `for-loop`, we can't access it outside the `for-loop`, so instead, you need to declare it outside of the `for-loop`, for example...

```
int m = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

This then allows us to declare a third array which will hold the final results we want, for example...

```
int[] arr3 = new int[m];
System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, arr3, 0, m);
return arr3;
```

Which will now output...

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 43]
```

Instead of...

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your second array with zero elements

```
 int arr2[] = {};
```

[Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) do not grow, so `arr2[0] = someValue` will give you an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) since there is no first element.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new array, you should specify it's size.

```
int arr2[] = {};
```

This creates an array of size 0. You probably get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution..this will print

> [1, 5, 7, 11, 43]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FunPrime {

public static ArrayList<Integer> calculate(int[] arr) {

    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(isPrime(arr[i]))
        {
            l.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return l;
}


static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int no[] = { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 22, 43 };
    System.out.println(calculate(no));
}

}
```

Comment: The question was 'what is wrong in this code', not 'how should one fix this' ;)